# Python - handle csv with 2 definition types

Tags: python, csv, numpy

How can I handle a csv file with two recurring definitions in the same file.

What I mean is that the file looks like this repeating with an increasing amount of race counts and multiple horses per race.

```
Meeting,05/07/14,RHIL,Rosehill Gardens,Weights,TAB,+3m Entire Circuit,          ,
Race,1,CIVIC STAKES,CIVIC,CIVIC,1350,~         ,3U        ,~         ,QLT       ,54,0,0,5/07/2014,,          ,          ,          ,          ,No class restriction, Quality, For Three-Years-Old and Upwards, No sex restriction, (Listed),Of $100000. First $60000, second $20000, third $10000, fourth $5000, fifth $2000, sixth $1000, seventh $1000, eighth $1000
Horse,1,Bennetta,0,"Grahame Begg",Randwick,,0,0,16-3-1-3 $390450.00,,0,0,0,,98.00,M,
Horse,2,Breakfast in Bed,0,"David Vandyke",Warwick Farm,,0,0,20-6-1-5 $201250.00,,0,0,0,,81.00,M,
Horse,3,Capital Commander,0,"Gerald Ryan",Rosehill,,0,0,43-9-9-3 $438625.00,,0,0,0,,85.00,M,
Horse,4,Coup Ay Tee (NZ),0,"Chris Waller",Rosehill,,0,0,35-9-6-5 $519811.00,,0,0,0,,101.00,G,
Horse,5,Generalife,0,"John O'Shea",Warwick Farm,,0,0,19-6-1-3 $235045.00,,0,0,0,,87.00,G,
Horse,6,He's Your Man (FR),0,"Chris Waller",Rosehill,,0,0,13-2-3-1 $108110.00,,0,0,0,,93.00,G,
Horse,7,Hidden Kisses,0,"Chris Waller",Rosehill,,0,0,40-8-8-5 $565750.00,,0,0,0,,96.00,M,
Horse,8,Oakfield Commands,0,"Gerald Ryan",Rosehill,,0,0,22-7-4-6 $269530.00,,0,0,0,,94.00,G,
Horse,9,Taxmeifyoucan,0,"Gregory Hickman",Warwick Farm,,0,0,18-2-4-4 $539730.00,,0,0,0,,91.00,G,
Horse,10,The Peak,0,"Bart & James Cummings",Randwick,,0,0,15-6-1-0 $426732.00,,0,0,0,,95.00,G,
Horse,11,Tougher Than Ever (NZ),0,"Chris Waller",Rosehill,,0,0,17-3-2-3 $321613.00,,0,0,0,,97.00,H,
Horse,12,TROMSO,0,"Chris Waller",Rosehill,,0,0,47-8-11-2 $622300.00,,0,0,0,,103.00,G,
Race,2,FLYING WELTER - BENCHMARK 95 HCP,BM95,BM95,1100,BM95      ,3U        ,~         ,HCP       ,54,0,0,5/07/2014,,          ,          ,          ,          ,BenchMark 95, Handicap, For Three-Years-Old and Upwards, No sex restriction,Of $85000. First $48750, second $16750, third $8350, fourth $4150, fifth $2000, sixth $1000, seventh $1000, eighth $1000, ninth $1000, tenth $1000
Horse,1,Big Bonanza,0,"Don Robb",Wyong,,0,57.5,31-9-4-3 $366860.00,,0,0,0,,92.00,G,
Horse,2,Casual Choice,0,"Joseph Pride",Warwick Farm,,0,54,8-2-3-0 $105930.00,,0,0,0,,80.00,G,
Horse,3,Cradle Me,0,"David Pfieffer",Warwick Farm,,0,54,28-7-4-2 $268215.00,,0,0,0,,89.00,M,
```

I can parse it out the standard way using reader and it obliges.

```
In [9]: with open('/home/sayth/Scripts/test.csv') as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(f_csv)
    for row in f_csv:
        print row

['Race', '1', 'CIVIC STAKES', 'CIVIC', 'CIVIC', '1350', '~         ', '3U        ', '~         ', 'QLT       ', '54', '0', '0', '5/07/2014', '', '          ', '          ', '          ', '          ', 'No class restriction', ' Quality', ' For Three-Years-Old and Upwards', ' No sex restriction', ' (Listed)', 'Of $100000. First $60000', ' second $20000', ' third $10000', ' fourth $5000', ' fifth $2000', ' sixth $1000', ' seventh $1000', ' eighth $1000']
['Horse', '1', 'Bennetta', '0', 'Grahame Begg', 'Randwick', '', '0', '0', '16-3-1-3 $390450.00', '', '0', '0', '0', '', '98.00', 'M', '']
['Horse', '2', 'Breakfast in Bed', '0', 'David Vandyke', 'Warwick Farm', '', '0', '0', '20-6-1-5 $201250.00', '', '0', '0', '0', '', '81.00', 'M', '']
```

However the definition of race and the information contained within isn't a header for horse at all containing 38 items. It would realistically be its own table linked to the horse table.

I have been reading the examples here [Python Cookbook](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch06.html#_solution_94) and they are great but assume a csv file with a standard header and data following.

using numpy and genfromtxt merely reports all error in file such as.

```
np.genfromtxt('/home/sayth/Scripts/test.csv',)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 38 columns instead of 5)
    Line #3 (got 3 columns instead of 5)
    Line #4 (got 6 columns instead of 5)
    Line #5 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #6 (got 6 columns instead of 5)
    Line #7 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #8 (got 6 columns instead of 5)
    Line #9 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
    Line #10 (got 4 columns instead of 5)
...
```

How should I handle such a file keeping relationship between race and horse in tact?

Comment: are the items listed in the "Race" rows intended to be the headers for the following "Horse" rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of the specifics, but I would start with something like this ...

```
races = []
racefound = False
with open('/home/sayth/Scripts/test.csv') as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(f_csv)
    for row in f_csv:
        if row[0] == 'Race':
            if racefound:
                races.append(raceinfo)
                raceinfo = {'info': row, 'horses': horses}
                racefound = True
            horses = []
        else:
            horses.append(row)
```

**UPDATE**:

If you want to use the Race rows as header information, something like this might be more what you want ..

```
with open('/home/sayth/Scripts/test.csv') as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(f_csv)
    for row in f_csv:
        if row[0] == 'Race':
            raceinfo = row
        else:
            print dict(zip(raceinfo,row))
```

Comment: little bit of a hack in there ( and an error I just fixed )

Comment: thanks definitely the second version makes sure the relationship stays the same and would make it easier to setup to insert into database. Might see if I can adapt it into getfromtxt as well as I really like the select columns option in there.